# why when i add large images into drawable-xxhdpi and load it into full size image view .. i get a pixels image?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, scale, android-drawable

i am loading images into a custom grid view into android and each time i click into an image i want to be displayed into another activity which will be a full screen image .. it works correctly but the images look poor and pixeld .. i mean like it was small and then i make it big even though the images are with good quality and good scale ratio .. here is the good of the activity that it display the full size image :

public class FullImageActivity2 extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image_activity2);   
            // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(position);
}
```

and here is the XML layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                </LinearLayout>
```

and here is the code in the main activity with grid view :

```
  gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override




 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) {

                        // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),           FullImageActivity2.class);
                        // passing array index
                         i.putExtra("id", mThumbIds[position]);
                            Log.d("ID", "" + mThumbIds[position]);
                             startActivity(i);
                    }   
                });


            return view;
```

Comment: or 898X920 like 96dpi

Comment: So, you answered yourself. They will stretch UP, resulting in a pixellation. And, due to the POOR RESOLUTION (consider that the ldpi resolution is 120 dpi - AND IT'S THE LOWEST EVER - xxhdpi is 480 dpi), the results are visibly scarce.

Comment: but i am afraid if i load high quality images .. it will cause out of memory exception :/ @Vyger

Comment: So, the alternatives are: scale the images and have them pixellated OR leave them unscaled but small sized.

Comment: or can i fix the out of memory thing?

Comment: You can try... here's an [article and code to download](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)